# Regex validation fails to stop invalid data

Tags: java, spring-boot, spock

Regex validation is not working in my integration testing. The spock test fails as I get a `200` response. The string regex validation is failing on the request param even for alphanumeric and integers. How can I fix this?

```java
def "GetDataByTopic should return 400 with invalid output case"() {
  when:
  def result = mvc.perform(
    MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("/data/getDataByTopic?topic=" + topic)
  )

  then:
  result
    .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.status().is4xxClientError())
    .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.jsonPath('$.error').exists())

  where:
  topic       | _
  "<%script>" | _
}
```

The controller class for the below method is annotatied using `@Validated`
REGEX for string is `^[-A-Za-z_]{0,255}$`

```java
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, path = "/getDataByTopic")
public Response getDataByTopic(
  @Valid
  @Pattern(
    regexp = REGEX_STRING_VALIDATION, 
    message = "Topic format is incorrect :  ${validatedValue}"
  )
  @RequestParam("topic") String topic
) {
  return dataService.getDataByTopic(topic);
}
```

Comment: Have you tried it without the `@Valid` annotation?

Comment: Yeah, doesn’t work.